# Why does TFS history command return "TF30063: You are not authorized to access ..." when workspaces command works

Tags: powershell, tfs, teamcity

I have a TeamCity build configuration using a Team Foundation Server (TFS) VCS root with agent-side checkout. It is successfully connecting to TFS and getting the repository. The TFS account has alternate credentials enabled and these credentials are used successfully by the VCS root.

Within the build configuration, I have a Powershell runner step issuing TFS commands using `tf.exe`.

The first command:

```
& "$tfExe" workspaces
```

executes successfully returning the workspace info ($tfExe is set to the tf.exe path).

Getting the history of the repository with:

```
& "$tfExe" history .  /noprompt /recursive /stopafter:1 /format:detailed
```

returns the message:

`TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://{projectName}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection.`

I have tried the history command with and without the `/login` parameter as follows:

```
& "$tfExe" history .  /noprompt /recursive /stopafter:1 /format:detailed /login:"$usernameAndPassword"
```

where I tried setting `$usernameAndPassword` to "##Live##\AltUserName,Password" and "AltUserName,Password" but both returned the same error.

Why does tf.exe work for the workspaces command but not for the history command and what is wrong with the way I am calling the history command with the credentials (bearing in mind that those credentials are the same as the ones used by the VCS root in TeamCity)?

Comment: Does the error display is run "& "$tfExe" workspaces /collection:https://{projectName}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection" command?

Answer (score 0):

First, double check if this command can work successfully without any authorization error in CMD directly.

And for the `/login:` option ,please try to use `/login:username,[password]`

Comment: No, it does not. I get the same error there. I'm not sure how the TeamCity TFS extension is managing to check out the code using the same credentials, yet when I try to do the same it doesn't work.